# В каком формате поставлять online видео для videoview андроида

Tags: android, videoview, online-video

Требования:

1. Поддержка большинством устройств
2. Качество не должно ухудшаться
3. Весит не так много (но 2 пункт важнее)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите [список поддерживаемых видеоформатов](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) в Android - зависит от версии

**Update** некоторые девайсы поддерживают и более широкий набор - зависит от вендора.